# Como limitar as chances de um jogador em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Amigos, estou desenvolvendo um jogo da forca simples em JavaScript, sem boneco, só com com um contador de chances, porém, não estou conseguindo **limitar as chances do jogador** e estou com alguns erros sintáticos. Poderiam me ajudar? Segue abaixo o código:

## HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jogo da Forca</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="all">
        <h1>JOGO DA FORCA</h1>
            <div id="campo">Palavra:
                <input type="password" id="tela" value="" />
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="resp" value="" onload="criarTracos();" />
            <div id="teclas">
                <br/>
                <input type="button" value="Q" id="Q" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="W" id="W" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="E" id="E" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="R" id="R" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="T" id="T" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="Y" id="Y" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="U" id="U" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="I" id="I" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="O" id="P" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <br/>
                <input type="button" value="A" id="A" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="S" id="S" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="D" id="D" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="F" id="F" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="G" id="G" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="H" id="H" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="J" id="J" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="K" id="K" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="L" id="L" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <br />
                <input type="button" value="Z" id="Z" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="X" id="X" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="C" id="C" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="V" id="V" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="B" id="B" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="N" id="N" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="M" id="M" onClick="preencher(value);">
                <input type="button" value="APAGAR" id="APAGAR" onClick="backspace(tela);" style="width=1000px;">
                <br/>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="iniciar" id="iniciar" onClick="iniciar(tela);">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Javascript:

```
var palavra = new Array();
var controlando = 0;
var cont = 0;
var tracos = [];
var conpt = 0; //controle
var jogadas = 5;

function preencher(valor) {
    var elemento = document.getElementById("tela");
    var value = elemento.value;
    if (controlando == 0) {
        elemento.value = value + valor;
    }
    if (controlando == 1) {
        preenchimento(valor);
        if (renan == 1) {
          jogadas = jogadas - 1;
          alert(jogadas);
        }
    }
 }

function preenchimento(valor) {
    var elemento = document.getElementById("resp");
    var value = elemento.value;
    var checando = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < palavra.length; i++) {
        if (valor == palavra[i]) {
            tracos[i] = valor;
            document.getElementById(valor).disabled = true;
            conpt = 2;
        } else conpt = 1;
    }
    if (conpt == 1) jogadas = jogadas - 1;
    elemento.value = tracos;
}

function backspace(campo) {
    valor = campo.value;
    tamanho = valor.length
    campo.value = valor.substring(0, tamanho - 1)
}

function iniciar(tela) {
    var copia = tela.value;
    document.getElementById("tela").disabled = 1; //checar se pode
    palavra = copia;
    controlando = 1;
    criarTracos();
}

function criarTracos(valor) {
    var elemento = document.getElementById("resp");
    var tam = palavra.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        tracos[i] = "__";
    }
    elemento.value = tracos;
}
```

Comment: Podemos ajudar, desde que seja com uma dúvida, não com o jogo completo.

Answer (score 1):

É muito simples controlar as jogadas, basta adicionar uma variavel de inicio `false` de forma que apenas se torne `true` se o jogador acertou, caso contrário continuará `false` e no fim do laço de repetição você deverá reduzir uma chance do contador(`jogadas`) e então informar ao usuário que ele errou e perdeu uma jogada e tem `x` jogadas restantes, e ao clicar em uma letra você deve ter um `if` controlando sua variável `jogadas`, de forma que se for menor que `5` avisará para o usuário que ele não tem mais chances suficientes, e deverá começar um novo jogo.

Também tomei a liberdade de estilizar com CSS o seu "jogo" e também adicionei um botão "Novo Jogo" e note que estou adicionando as letras do teclado dinamicamente por isto podes alterar quando quiser, fica melhor desta forma.

Ps: também havia alguns erros de sintaxe e de lógica, foram corrigidos, ficaria desta forma:

```js
        function adicionaLetras(){
       var str = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
       for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++)
       {
         var nextChar = str.charAt(i);
            var ele      = document.createElement('input');
            ele.name     = nextChar;
            ele.value    = nextChar;
            ele.type     = 'button';
            ele.id       = nextChar;
            ele.onclick  = function(){ preencher(this.id) };
            document.getElementById('teclas').appendChild(ele);
          }
        }

        function preencher(valor){
          if (jogadas > 0){
          var elemento = document.getElementById("tela");
          var value = elemento.value;
          
          if (controlando == 0) {
              elemento.value = value + valor;
          }
          if (controlando == 1) {
              preenchimento(valor);
          }
          }else{
            alert('Desculpe, acabaram suas jogadas, por favor, inicie um novo jogo.');
          }
        }
  

        function preenchimento(valor){
          var acertou = false;
          var elemento = document.getElementById("resp");
            for (var i = 0; i < palavra.length; i++) {
              if (valor == palavra[i]) {
                tracos[i] = valor;
                document.getElementById(valor).disabled = true;
                acertou = true;
              }
            }
          elemento.value = tracos;
          if (acertou)
            alert("Você acertou, ainda tem "+jogadas+" jogadas.");
          else{
            jogadas--;
            alert("Você errou, você tem apenas "+jogadas+" jogadas restantes");
          }
        }
            function backspace(campo) {
                valor = campo.value;
                tamanho = valor.length
                campo.value = valor.substring(0, tamanho - 1)
            }

            function iniciar(tela) {
                jogadas = 5;
                var copia = tela.value;
                document.getElementById("tela").disabled = 1; 
                palavra = copia;
                controlando = 1;
                criarTracos();
            }

            function criarTracos(valor) {
                var elemento = document.getElementById("resp");
                var tam = palavra.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
                    tracos[i] = "__";
                }
                elemento.value = tracos;

            }

        window.palavra = new Array();
        window.controlando = 0;
        window.cont = 0;
        window.tracos = [];
        window.jogadas = 5;        
        adicionaLetras();
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 11pt
}
#teclas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#teclas span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#campo {
  height: 170px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  padding: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 270px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid deepskyblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

#teclas input[type=button] {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

#campo > input {
  width: 97%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#campo > input[type=button] {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.container input {
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div id="campo">
    Palavra Inicial:
    <input type="password" id="tela" value="" />
    Advinhação:
    <input type="text" id="resp" value="" onload="criarTracos();" />
  <input type="button" value="Apagar" id="APAGAR" onClick="backspace(tela);" />
  <input type="button" value="Iniciar jogo" id="iniciar" onClick="iniciar(tela);">
  <input type="button" value="Novo jogo" id="newgame" onClick="window.location.reload();">
  </div>
  <div id=teclas>
  <span>Teclado</span>
  </div>  
</div>
```